# STEAM: Failed to Initialize game server with Steam - Warning unable to Host

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, steam

I am following this tutorial "https://medium.com/swlh/ue4-tutorial-how-to-connect-a-multiplayer-game-with-steam-ccc89bd8d8a9" to use Steam with Unreal.

The project file is here: https://github.com/bluebubblebee/UE4_CoopPuzzleGame/tree/master/CoopPuzzleGame/Source

After making changes to the ini file to set Steam as DefaultPlatformService I can't host!!

I get "STEAM: Failed to Initialize game server with Steam!! - No session created" and OnCreateSessionComplete session fails. I am not able to logout what is causing the issue. It only has the issue with online session, if its a lan session it creates the Session.

[image]

Project works in UE 4.26. I want it to work using Unreal Version 4.27.

Not sure what is causing the issue!!

Comment: Wild guess: Steam won't talk to you without an App Id. Are you setting it somewhere? I can't see it. For testing you can use the 480 that's mentioned in the tutorial. For actual use you would have to get your own.

Comment: @dratenik Yes I am setting the APP id as well in the ini file as shown. The projects in 4.26. Its just it doesnt work in 4.27.

Comment: A UE 4.27 bug then? The forums mention something about steam auth being broken https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/advanced-sessions-plugin/30020/2979

Comment: wait for 4.27.1???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it seems it is a problem in version 4.27 as @dratenik pointed out that it breaks the advanced session plugin.

As suggested in the forum steam works if I set SessionSettings.bUseLobbiesIfAvailable = true;

It works even if I set DataAdvertisementType to ViaOnlineService. It works on 2 PCs on 2 different steam accounts, but I have not tested running the game over the internet with another PC on an another network.

This still seems an in between solution and hopefully we get a proper solution in the future.